# What is meant by "replicating an American option"?

Tags: american-options

What does it mean to say that we "replicate an American option" in the usual structure of an asset-pricing model with a measure Q?

I mean, any portfolio with an adapted and self-financing strategy *will* be a martingale. But the payoff of an American option will in general **not** be a martingale.

So when people talk about replicating an American option, what do they really mean? Do they mean replicating an American option's payoff **assuming optimal behavior**? So really we try to replicate the *stopped* payoff process?